# Initializing first instance of variable in dictionary

Tags: python

In JavaScript, if I need to keep a counter of each individual character of a string and store it in a dictionary, I can initialize the first instance of that character to `1` before incrementing it. For example:

```
const frequency = {};
const place = "Disney World";

for (const c of place) {
    frequency[c] = (frequency[c] + 1 || 1);
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this in Python?

Comment: yes, python supports two pretty cool things for this. 1: Did you know python actually comes with a `collections.Counter` class? 2: the behaviour you seek is something called defaultdicts. Dictionaries with a default value for all keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `defaultdict` for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
frequency = defaultdict(lambda:1)
```

Now keys will have automatically have a value of 1.

Comment: Did the default ought to be 0 instead of 1, so that when the key for a new character is created, and then the count is incremented, it will be 1?  If you started at one, this would lead to the count being 2...

Comment: Right; `defaultdict(int)` then :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if that letter is an existing key in the dictionary, and if not, create it and set its value to 1, else increment the value like this:

```
frequency = {};
place = "Disney World";

for c in place:
    if c in frequency:
        frequency[c] += 1
    else:
        frequency[c] = 1

print(frequency)
# {'D': 1, 'i': 1, 's': 1, 'n': 1, 'e': 1, 'y': 1, ' ': 1, 'W': 1, 'o': 1, 'r': 1, 'l': 1, 'd': 1}
```

**EDIT:**

Following the mention of `defaultdict`, here is a full example of using it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# using 0 so, when incremented, the first value becomes 1
frequency = defaultdict(int)

for c in place:
    frequency[c] += 1

print(dict(frequency))
# {'D': 1, 'i': 1, 's': 1, 'n': 1, 'e': 1, 'y': 1, ' ': 1, 'W': 1, 'o': 1, 'r': 1, 'l': 1, 'd': 1}
```

Comment: Instead of `lambda:0`, you can use `int`. Also, `if c in frequency.keys()` can be sped up with `if c in frequency`.

Comment: Thanks for editing, +1 for highlighting both methods.

Answer (score 2):

For references, there is a class for that in the standard library:

```
from collections import Counter
place = "Disney World"
frequency = Counter(place)
```

You directly get a dictionary like object where the letters are the keys and the value the counts.